# Spring, Jetty Maven Plugin: No qualifying bean error only after jetty reload

Tags: java, spring, maven, web-applications, jetty

I have set up a simple web application using Eclipse, Maven, embeded H2 DB and Jetty maven plugin.

Everything works nicely when I

```
mvn jetty:run
```

all the dependencies are resolved and the webapp runs without a problem.

After I change a source file, jetty will reload (I tried manual reloading, same result) and throw this error every time. And always on the same service class (which has been autowired successfully at first startup).

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [li.grillplaetz.service.directory.DirectoryService] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:986)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:856)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:795)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:723)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:196)

What could be wrong here? I reckon that if I was missing something in my code, it shouldn't work from the start. But this only happens after jetty reload. When I kill jetty and run it again, all is fine.

I configured jetty like this in my pom.xml and I'm using spring 3.2.

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <reload>manual</reload>
        <!-- <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>-->
    </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Any insight is appreciated.
Thanks
Marc

Comment: Did you implement the `DirectoryService` in your application? I seems that Spring doesn't find a implementation to run at startup.

Comment: Of course I did, as I said, it all works fine after the first startup. There is also no ambiguity. Only one implementation is in the scan-packages. And it is found and wired initially, but not after a jetty reload.

Comment: Did You use `@Autowired` and `@Qualifier` annotations?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Only `@Autowired`. As I understand, `@Qualifier` is only needed when more than one candidate exists.

Comment: Oh Ok! I was thinking that maybe there is more than one candidate to autowiring =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, this is a known bug in Jetty 9.

It should be fixed in the latest version 9.0.4, which doesn't seem to be available on maven repos as per now.
So, my workaround was to revert to Jetty 8 for the time being, which doesn't have this bug.